# How to use JSF tags in resource bundles / How to rewrite URLs in a resource bundle?

Tags: java, jsf, seam, resourcebundle

Enviornment: 
JSF 2.1.7
SEAM 2.3.0
JBOSS 5.1.2

My application has a string that needs to be localized

> "I agree to WorldSite's *Privacy Policy* and *Cookie Notice*"

Where the italicized *Privacy Policy* and *Cookie Notice* are hyperlinks to other pages.

Originally our facelet was set up like this:

```
<h:outputText value="#{messages['iAgreeTo']}" />
<h:outputLink target="_blank" value="#{bean.privacyPolicy}">#{messages['privacyPolicy']}</h:outputLink>
<h:outputText value="#{messages['and']}"/>
<h:outputLink target="_blank" value="/jsf/Notice.xhtml">
    <h:outputText value="#{messages['cookieNotice']}"/>
    <f:param name="content" value="Cookie-Notice"/>
    <f:param name="application" value="#{bean.application}"/>
</h:outputLink>
```

Note: We have URL rewriting in place that takes /jsf/Notice.xhtml and rewrites to

```
rewrite pattern: /#{application}/Notice/#{content}
result:http://contextRoot/contextPath/myApp/Notice/Cookie-Notice
```

This allowed for piecemeal translations of the individual keys

```
iAgreeTo=I agree to WorldSite's&#160;
privacyPolicy=Privacy Policy
and=&#160;and&#160;
cookieNotice=Cookie Notice
```

But this required a workaround for some languages (in "iAgreeTo" and "and" keys)

```
iAgreeTo=J'accepte la&#160;
privacyPolicy=Politique de la vie privée
and=&#160;de WorldSite et les&#160;
cookieNotice=Note D'information sur les Cookies
```

**Ideally I would like to be able to have the links be movable within the key. Something like this:**

```
iAgreePhrase=I agree to WorldSite's #{messages['privacyPolicyLink']} and the #{messages['cookieNoticeLink']}
privacyPolicy=Privacy Policy
cookieNotice=Cookie Notice

//The following non-translatable keys held in a separate file
privacyPolicyLink=<h:outputLink target="_blank" value="#{bean.privacyPolicy}">#{messages['privacyPolicy']}</h:outputLink>
cookieNoticeLink=<h:outputLink target="_blank" id="cookieNoticeLink" value="/jsf/Notice.xhtml">\
    #{messages['cookieNotice']}\
    <f:param name="content" value="Cookie-Notice"/>\
    <f:param name="application" value="#{bean.application}"/>\
</h:outputLink>
```

But the facelet returns the JSF tags (h:outputLink) as strings instead of expanding them to their HTML tags. **I can use `<a>` tags, but then I'm putting rewrite logic in the properties file which is difficult to maintain**

```
iAgreePhrase=I agree to WorldSite's #{messages['privacyPolicyLink']} and the #{messages['cookieNoticeLink']}
privacyPolicy=Privacy Policy
cookieNotice=Cookie Notice

//The following non-translatable keys held in a separate file
privacyPolicyLink=<a target="_blank" href="#{bean.privacyPolicy}">#{messages['privacyPolicy']}</a>
cookieNoticeLink=<a target="_blank" href="#{contextPath}/#{bean.application}/Notice/Terms-and-Conditions">\
    #{messages['cookieNotice']}</a>
```

Is there a way I can achieve my desired effect without having to put rewrite logic in the resource bundle? Some thoughts I have are forcing the application container to process the facelet twice/reorder it, so it inserts the resource bundles first, and then expands the JSF tags.

Alternatively I may be able to construct the rewritten URL in a bean then call that from my resource bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [Oversteer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12427429/1417546) is certainly applicable, this could also prove helpful. You can create URLs from EL expressions like this:

```
#{facesContext.externalContext.encodeActionURL('/myapp/Notice/Privacy-Policy')}
```

To include HTML markup in a message, you need to use `escape="false"` in `<h:outputText/>`, for example:

```
<h:outputText escape="false" value="#{messages['iAgreePhrase']}" />
```

And, in your messages.properties (or localized version):

```
iAgreePhrase=I agree to WorldSite's <a href="#{facesContext.externalContext.encodeActionURL('/myapp/Notice/Privacy-Policy')}">Privacy Policy</a> and ...
```

This has the problem that the URL is calculable only from within an HTTP request, if you for example use the message key from within an asynchronous thread, the URL will not be calculated (there's no facesContext available).

Comment: After reading the doc - so if my facelet were "/jsf/Notice.xhtml" I could encodeActionUrl('/jsf/Notice.xhtml?content=Privacy-Policy&application=myApp') and it would return /myApp/Notice/Privacy-Policy ?

if so I believe this is my answer

Comment: This works. as an aside it should be encodeActionURL, in uppercase

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have got everything round the wrong way and I'm sorry to have to say that I found the question poorly analysed, overlong and confusing to read.

What you should be trying to do is use resource bundles from within JSF tags and not the other way round. Where you need to parameterise a message you use a construct such as this:

**messages.properties**

```
nameHeader=My name is {0}
```

**index.xhtml**

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{msgs.nameHeader}">
    <f:param value="#{bean.name}"/>
</h:outputFormat>
```

If you have a scenario where this doesn't work you would have to build the string in a backing bean.

Comment: Also, if you want to build a little more complex like TEXTWITHLINK (containing someplace a link), you could have a `LINK=terms` entry, and a `TEXTWITHLINK=Do you agree with {0}` entry. Then you use the first term to build the `<a href=...>text</a>` and then use that value to build the complete output using the other message with placeholders.

Comment: Sorry the question was a bit verbose. This answer doesn't help because it doesn't allow movable links within the key. Helio's response is similar to what I was doing in the keys themselves. However I cannot use <a> tags within the link because then I would be rewriting URLs explicitly in my facelet, instead of letting seam control the rewriting, which is hard to maintain.

Comment: As an edit to the above - The answer is helpful in that I should be using outputFormat instead of having a key within my key. The answer is NOT helpful in that I am rewriting URLs explicitly in my facelet, instead of letting seam control the rewriting.